# How does the NullpointerException is not throwing when i use int?

Tags: java

I have two different programs, the one that uses `int` and the other `Double`.
For the below code am getting `NullpointerException`

```
public class Solution {

    Double cost;
    void addTax(Double b)
    {
        cost+=b;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        new Solution().addTax(30.00);
    }
}
```

But for the below code that uses int isn't getting any runtime error.

```
public class Solution {

    int cost;

    void addTax(int b)
    {
        cost+=b;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        new Solution().addTax(30);
    }
}
```

So how does that possible? Please explain me.

Comment: Essentially `Double` is a wrapper over `double`. Unlike `int`, which is a primitive and gets automatically initialized to 0, `Double` is an actual object which requires initialization.

Answer (score 3):

A primitive (such as `int`) gets a default value of `0`, while a reference type (such as `Double`) gets a default value of `null`.

Therefore `cost+=b;` throws a `NullPointerException` in the first code snippet (since it's equivalent to `cost = cost.doubleValue() + b;`), while in the second snippet it is equivalent to `cost = 0 + b;`, which is fine.

Comment: I defer to your faster typing skills and have deleted my answer. :-)

Answer (score 2):

`Double` is a wrapper over `double`. Since `Double` will be set to `null` when your class's instance is initialized, trying to increment its value (which involves *unboxing* from `Double` to `double` will cause NPE.

Default value of `int` is `0`, so no NPE Hurray :)

Answer (score 1):

In first example you're using class Double and in second one just primitive type int. My guess is that you did it by mistake and you probably you just wanted to use primitive type 'double'